# Parse Json to DBObject

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I have a `REST` service which consumes "*test/plain*", basically the string I receive is a `JSON` string, I have the following code to parse the `JSON` string to `DBObject` so that I can save it to `MongoDB`.

```
@Timed
@POST
@Consumes("text/plain")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response insertscreenview(String message) {
    // System.out.println(message);
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScreenviewResource.class);
    logger.info("Screenview Insert Request Recieved" + "\n" + message);
    screenviewInstance = new Screenview();
    tracInfoInstance = new TracInfo();
    BasicDBObject ageRangeId;
    GeoCheckManager geoCheckInstance = new GeoCheckManager();
    boolean brCheck;        
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree(message);

        System.out.println(message);

        DBObject objInstance = (DBObject)JSON.parse(message);
 ...}
```

My `JSON` string look's as follow

```
{
"Screenview": {
    "TracInfo": null,
    "Id": 0,
    "ScreenName": "SettingsActivity",
    "Timestamp": "2014-07-02T18:50:10",
    "Timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
    "ApplicationId": null,
    "DeviceId": null,
    "UserId": null,
    "SessionId": "5684ae84-9a48-49a5-ab47-fcb7de3c08cf"
},
"Session": {
    "Id": "5684ae84-9a48-49a5-ab47-fcb7de3c08cf",
    "StartTime": "2014-07-02T13:20:58",
    "EndTime": "2014-07-02T13:21:09",
    "EntryScreen": "AccessPointActivity",
    "ExitScreen": "SettingsActivity",
    "FirstEvent": "SCREEN STARTED",
    "LastEvent": "SCREEN STOPPED",
    "ApplicationId": "fa41f204bfc711e3b9f9c8cbb8c502c4",
    "DeviceId": "0_6e505bcbe7e511e393b60aba4a7caa0b",
    "UserId": "",
    "TracInfoId": -1,
    "SensorsInfo": null
},
"CustomParams": {
    "Latitude": 0,
    "Longitude": 0,
    "Country": null,
    "CountryCode": null,
    "Region": null,
    "RegionCode": null,
    "City": null,
    "Gender": null,
    "Age": 0,
    "Platform": "Android",
    "OSVersion": "16",
    "Manufacturer": "samsung",
    "Resolution": "600 * 976",
    "NetworkCarrier": null,
    "Timezone": null
} }
```

It gives me error as follow and I am unable to find why.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to
>   com.mongodb.DBObject

Comment: For starters you should be consuming "application/json" if JSON is your input. People do REST wrong all the time where MIME types are not considered. But at least get that part right even if JSON is your only accepted input. **P.S** : We need the code or reference to the part that is doing the parsing. A good implementation will fail for exactly what I just said.

Comment: Guessing that this is not the `com.mongodb.util` implementation of `JSON.parse` make sure which you are importing.

Comment: Thought that might be it. Fat fingered things like that in IDE's a couple of times.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `DBObject`, you could make use of `BasicDBObject` which has a constructor taking Map as input:

`BasicDBObject obj= new BasicDBObject(JSON.parse(message));`

or using ObjectMapper:

`BasicDBObject obj = mapper.readValue(message, BasicDBObject.class);`

Comment: `com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(String)` returns an Object, not a Map. If it is not a boxed primitive value you can safely cast it to DBObject.

Answer (score 2):

More up to date way of parsing a string to a DBObject:

```
BasicDBObject dbObject = com.mongodb.BasicDBObject.parse(rawJsonString)
```

Note that this should probably only be used for free schemas json objects, most of the time something like Springs MongoDBTemplate/MongoRepository etc. can be used to take care of the mapping.