# MongoDb compact command using spring boot MongoTemplate

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongo-shell, mongotemplate

Mongo shell command:

```
db.runCommand({compact: <collection name>})
```

**How can I run same command using `MongoTemplate` in Spring Boot project?**

I tried with:

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
...
mongoTemplate.executeCommand(jsonCommand);
...
```

but it supports only commands in json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-document/docs/jdiff-mongo-m2-m3/mongo-report/Version%201.0.0%20M3/org/springframework/data/document/mongodb/MongoTemplate.html) you can call `executeCommand` using `DBObject` or `String` as a parameter.

So one option is simply get the JSON as String:

```java
String jsonCommand = "{compact: " + collectionName + "}";
mongoTemplate.executeCommand(jsonCommand);
```

Or create the `DBObject`:

```java
DBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject("compact", collectionName );
mongoTemplate.executeCommand(dbObject);
```

Or even, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60717743/13464279) you can create the `DBObject` from a JSON:

```java
BasicDBObject dbObject = com.mongodb.BasicDBObject.parse(jsonCommand)
mongoTemplate.executeCommand(dbObject);
```